# Рамка вокруг меню

Tags: html, css

Стоит задача вокруг меню сделать рамку. Сложную, с виньетками, часть из которых слегка залезает на меню. (Типа как рамка монитора частично закрывает экран.) Ширина - резиновая.

Как эта задача решается по-умному? У меня три варианта одинаково противных:

1. отрицательный margin
2. position: relative
3. float: left

[image: рамка]

Comment: Непоняяятно, дизайн в студию!

Comment: Непонятна как ситуация, так и то, что вы хотите реализовать.

Comment: можно попробовать z-слоями с дивами с png бэкграундами

Comment: Можно попробовать z-слоями с дивами с png бэкграундами.

Comment: Ну, вот так оно.
z-слоями не хочется. Опасаюсь без нужды пользовать абсолют

Comment: а за счет чего тут происходит растяжение?
огого интересная задачка

Comment: Недавно на релативах делал, слайдер с зед-слоями все вроде нормально.

Comment: Да с растяжением все просто: справа и слева от центра растягиваются вот эти желтые планки. "Уши" разъезжаются, а центральный шилдик остается по-центру.
Ладно, пока чделаю по-своему, если получится чисто, выложу как ответ

Comment: А тупо табличка - как всегда "фу" и несолидно?

Comment: Ну зачем так сразу? Ничего не имею против таблиц, если умеючи. Просто ума не приложу как она тут сможет помочь с накладными элементами.

Comment: Кнопки по центру или тоже резина?

Comment: Кнопки, к счастью, фиксированной ширины. Но их может быть сколько угодно, лишние скроет overflow: hidden;
Концепт плохой, но хотят ТАК. =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С табличкой я прогнал, конечно) Ну тогда совет простой - делим на 3 части. сперва ссылки, поверх центральный кусочек. следом правый и левый (для левого: **float: left; height: 100px; margin-top: -100px;** ). Остальное, додумаете, мне кажется)

Моя наработка:

```
<style type="text/css">
  body, html { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
  div { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
  #des {margin: 10px 20px;}
  #left,#left-inner,#right,#right-inner { border: #0f0 1px dashed; background-color: #0f0; width: 40px; height: 100px; float: left; margin: -102px 0px 0px 0px; }
  #left-inner,#right-inner { margin: 0px; position: absolute; }
  #right { float: right; }
  #links { border: #f00 1px dashed; margin: 0px 35px 0px 35px; padding: 60px 0px 10px 0px; height: 30px; overflow: hidden; }
  #c { margin: -20px auto 20px auto; width: 1px; height: 1px; }
  #c2 { position: absolute; border: #0f0 1px dashed; background-color: #0f0; width: 40px; height: 20px; margin: -5px 0px 0px -20px; }
  #links a { display: block; background-color: #00f; text-align: center; width: 120px; height: 30px; }
  #links a:hover { background-color: #f00; }
</style>
<div id="des">
  <div id="links">
    <table align="center">
      <tr>
        <td><a href="/">1</a></td>
        <td><a href="/">1</a></td>
        <td><a href="/">1</a></td>
        <td><a href="/">1</a></td>
        <td><a href="/">1</a></td>
        <td><a href="/">1</a></td>
        <td><a href="/">1</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="c"><div id="c2"></div></div>
  <div id="left"><div id="left-inner"></div></div>
  <div id="right"><div id="right-inner"></div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Идея такая: вы уж извините, спать хочу сильно.

```
<div class="menuSuperBottom">кнопки. самый-самый низ</div>
<!-- верх -->
<div class="bottomTop">верхняя середина. резина.под верхними</div>
<div class="leftTop">левый верхний угол</div>
<div class="rightTop">правый верхний угол</div>
<!-- верх конец -->
<!-- середина -->
<div class="leftMiddle">левый бок</div>
<div class="rightMiddle">правый бок</div>
<!-- середина конец -->
<!-- низ -->
<div class="bottomBottom">нижний слой полоска. низ</div>
<div class="leftBottom">нижний угол. левый. низ</div>
<div class="centerBottom">середина низ</div>
<div class="rightBottom">правый нижний угол. низ</div>
<!-- низ конец -->
```

Индексы указать по порядку, как в коде, в порядке возрастания.

Позиционирование: релатив, марджины указать отрицательные на усмотрение.
(-продолжу если не усну...-)

```
<style>
.menuSuperBottom, .bottomTop, .leftTop, .rightTop, .leftMiddle, .rightMiddle, .bottomBottom, centerBottom, rightBottom{
position:relative;
margin: добавить по вкусу;
padding:тоже самое, на свое усмотрение;
}
.menuSuperBottom{
z-index:1;
width:100%;
left:0;/*не знаю надо ли это*/
right:0;/*не знаю надо ли это*/
}
.bottomTop{
z-index:2;
background-image:url(верхняя растягивающаяся полоса\путь);
background-repeat: xxx;/*что бы не повторялся по вертикали*/
}
.leftTop{
z-index:3;
background-image:url(левый угол\путь);
bakground-repeat: none;
float:left;
}
.rightTop{
z-index:4;
background-image:url(правый угол\путь);
bakground-repeat: none;
clear:right;
right:0;
}
.middleLeft{
z-index:5;
background-image:url(левая сторона\путь);
bakground-repeat: none;
float:left;
}
.middleRight{
z-index:6;
background-image:url(правая сторона\путь);
bakground-repeat: none;
clear:right;
right:0;
}
.bottomBottom{
z-index:7;
background-image:url(левый угол\путь);
bakground-repeat: none;
/*аналогично верхнему тянеться*/
}
.leftBottom{
z-index:8;
background-image:url(левый угол\путь);
background-repeat: xxx;/*что бы не повторялся по вертикали*/
float:left;
}
.centerBottom{
z-index:9;
background-image:url(нижняя.центр\путь);
background-repeat: xxx;/*что бы не повторялся по вертикали*/
left:50%
width: %wVar%;/*по вкусу вписать значение*/
margin-left: -%wVar%
/*что то я еще забыл, что бы блок был отцентрован?*/
float:left;
}
.leftBottom{
z-index:10;
background-image:url(правый угол\путь);
background-repeat: xxx;/*что бы не повторялся по вертикали*/
clear:right;
right:0;
}
</style>
```

Внимание, там где-то ошибки и неточности, но я надеюсь, более опытные люди, исправят, если что.

Размеры надо еще указать и отступы. Извиняюсь, если это "велосипед".

(Кстати, svg такие штуки можно делать? Если да, то, они проще? Что с браузерами?)

Comment: есть еще
border-image, но я про него ничего не знаю кроме того, что можно для каждой части (углы\стороны) использовать картинку свою

Comment: Вот что-то типа делаю я. =//
Мне кажется, это как-то неправильно. =)